# was looking or looked in this sentence

Tags: usage, continuous

> When I woke up this morning, she was sleeping on my bed and she looked very happy!

The sentence is about a female cat who was ill.

Why isn't *was looking* (at this precise moment she was looking)? Since she was ill, the sentence I quoted seems to imply her happiness won't last for long.

Comment: To me, there's no real difference between *You look good today* and *You're looking good today*. But whereas ***You look good** in that little black dress* sounds perfectly natural, ***You are looking good** in that little black dress* sounds like something only an "Indian English" speaker would say. And even the idiomatically contracted ***You're looking good** in that little black dress* could sound at least a little bit "odd" in many contexts. In your *exact* context, past continuous would be less likely, but it's perfectly okay - it just emphasises that the cat *continued* to look happy.

Comment: Source of the sentence? Your sentence sounds kinda sus.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence sounds OK, and there's some logic in the difference between tenses. She '*looked good*' *at the moment* **he** looked or glanced at her after he woke up - that was *his* short-time perception of her, while **she** definitely was sleeping *continuously*. '*You're looking good*' is typically said by the 'beholder' *while looking at* someone.